# Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1 (Android Studio)

Tags: android, firebase, flutter

I am trying to run my flutter app and I face this problem after installing firebase_auth and I try to uninstall it and run the app the problem still exist and I'v try `flutter clean` and I search for the solution and did not find it.
Sorry for the long error

```
    Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\my name\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\.dart_tool\flutter_build\ac53bddf60bdda743e2fbab28241e046\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: C:\Users\my name\AndroidStudioProjects\flutter_app\.dart_tool\flutter_build\ac53bddf60bdda743e2fbab28241e046\kernel_snapshot.d
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/top_level.dart:16:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
       ^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js-0.6.2/lib/js.dart:8:1: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
export 'dart:js' show allowInterop, allowInteropCaptureThis;
^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js-0.6.2/lib/js_util.dart:8:1: Error: Not found: 'dart:js_util'
export 'dart:js_util';
^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/auth.dart:306:25: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase/src/auth.dart' ('../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var nextWrapper = allowInterop((firebase_interop.UserJsImpl user) {
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/auth.dart:310:26: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase/src/auth.dart' ('../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) => _changeController.addError(e));
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/auth.dart:340:25: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase/src/auth.dart' ('../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var nextWrapper = allowInterop((firebase_interop.UserJsImpl user) {
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/auth.dart:345:11: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase/src/auth.dart' ('../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
          allowInterop((e) => _idTokenChangedController.addError(e));
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart:164:9: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'DatabaseReference<T>'.
 - 'DatabaseReference' is from 'package:firebase/src/database.dart' ('../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
        allowInterop((update) => jsify(transactionUpdate(dartify(update))));
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart:166:26: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'DatabaseReference<T>'.
 - 'DatabaseReference' is from 'package:firebase/src/database.dart' ('../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    var onCompleteWrap = allowInterop(
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart:301:24: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Query<T>'.
 - 'Query' is from 'package:firebase/src/database.dart' ('../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    var callbackWrap = allowInterop((database_interop.DataSnapshotJsImpl data,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart:325:30: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Query<T>'.
 - 'Query' is from 'package:firebase/src/database.dart' ('../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    jsObject.once(eventType, allowInterop(
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart:402:22: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'DataSnapshot'.
 - 'DataSnapshot' is from 'package:firebase/src/database.dart' ('../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/database.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    var actionWrap = allowInterop((d) => action(DataSnapshot.getInstance(d)));
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/messaging.dart:72:27: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Messaging'.
 - 'Messaging' is from 'package:firebase/src/messaging.dart' ('../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/messaging.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      final nextWrapper = allowInterop((payload) {
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/messaging.dart:75:28: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Messaging'.
 - 'Messaging' is from 'package:firebase/src/messaging.dart' ('../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/messaging.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      final errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) {
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/messaging.dart:87:27: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Messaging'.
 - 'Messaging' is from 'package:firebase/src/messaging.dart' ('../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/messaging.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      final nextWrapper = allowInterop((payload) {
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/messaging.dart:97:27: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Messaging'.
 - 'Messaging' is from 'package:firebase/src/messaging.dart' ('../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/messaging.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      final nextWrapper = allowInterop((_) => null);
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/messaging.dart:98:28: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Messaging'.
 - 'Messaging' is from 'package:firebase/src/messaging.dart' ('../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/messaging.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      final errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) {
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/storage.dart:317:11: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'UploadTask'.
 - 'UploadTask' is from 'package:firebase/src/storage.dart' ('../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/storage.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
          allowInterop((storage_interop.UploadTaskSnapshotJsImpl data) {
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/storage.dart:321:26: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'UploadTask'.
 - 'UploadTask' is from 'package:firebase/src/storage.dart' ('../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/storage.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) => _changeController.addError(e));
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/storage.dart:322:26: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'UploadTask'.
 - 'UploadTask' is from 'package:firebase/src/storage.dart' ('../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/storage.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var onCompletion = allowInterop(() => _changeController.close());
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/top_level.dart:195:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
  if (js.hasProperty(error, 'message')) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/top_level.dart:196:19: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
    var message = js.getProperty(error, 'message');
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:29:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
  if (util.hasProperty(jsObject, 'firestore') &&
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:30:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
      util.hasProperty(jsObject, 'id') &&
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:31:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
      util.hasProperty(jsObject, 'parent')) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:37:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
  if (util.hasProperty(jsObject, 'latitude') &&
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:38:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
      util.hasProperty(jsObject, 'longitude') &&
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:44:15: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
  var proto = util.getProperty(jsObject, '__proto__');
              ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:46:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
  if (util.hasProperty(proto, 'toDate') &&
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:47:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
      util.hasProperty(proto, 'toMillis')) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:52:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
  if (util.hasProperty(proto, 'isEqual') &&
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:53:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
      util.hasProperty(proto, 'toBase64')) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:67:24: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
    map[key] = dartify(util.getProperty(jsObject, key));
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:91:17: Error: Method not found: 'newObject'.
    var jsMap = util.newObject();
                ^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:93:7: Error: Method not found: 'setProperty'.
      util.setProperty(jsMap, key, jsify(value));
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:116:12: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    return allowInterop(dartObject);
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:124:5: Error: Method not found: 'callMethod'.
    util.callMethod(jsObject, method, args);
    ^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:139:19: Error: Method not found: 'promiseToFuture'.
    value = await util.promiseToFuture(thenable);
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:141:9: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
    if (util.hasProperty(e, 'code')) {
        ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:152:27: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
  return PromiseJsImpl<S>(allowInterop((
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:165:5: Error: Method not found: 'allowInterop'.
    allowInterop(c.completeError);
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:173:22: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
  String get code => util.getProperty(_source, 'code');
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:176:25: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
  String get message => util.getProperty(_source, 'message');
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:179:22: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
  String get name => util.getProperty(_source, 'name');
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:182:32: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
  Object get serverResponse => util.getProperty(_source, 'serverResponse');
                               ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/utils.dart:185:23: Error: Method not found: 'getProperty'.
  String get stack => util.getProperty(_source, 'stack');
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/firestore.dart:105:30: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Firestore'.
 - 'Firestore' is from 'package:firebase/src/firestore.dart' ('../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    var updateFunctionWrap = allowInterop((transaction) =>
                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/firestore.dart:306:11: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'DocumentReference'.
 - 'DocumentReference' is from 'package:firebase/src/firestore.dart' ('../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
          allowInterop((firestore_interop.DocumentSnapshotJsImpl snapshot) {
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/firestore.dart:310:26: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'DocumentReference'.
 - 'DocumentReference' is from 'package:firebase/src/firestore.dart' ('../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
      var errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) => controller.addError(e));
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/firestore.dart:445:9: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Query<T>'.
 - 'Query' is from 'package:firebase/src/firestore.dart' ('../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
        allowInterop((firestore_interop.QuerySnapshotJsImpl snapshot) {
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/firestore.dart:449:24: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Query<T>'.
 - 'Query' is from 'package:firebase/src/firestore.dart' ('../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    var errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) => controller.addError(e));
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/firestore.dart:775:9: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'QuerySnapshot'.
 - 'QuerySnapshot' is from 'package:firebase/src/firestore.dart' ('../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/firestore.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
        allowInterop((s) => callback(DocumentSnapshot.getInstance(s)));
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
../../Desktop/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-7.3.0/lib/src/interop/js_interop.dart:17:7: Error: Method not found: 'hasProperty'.
  if (util.hasProperty(jsObject, 'toDateString')) {
      ^^^^^^^^^^^
U
nhandled exception:
FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml;
 message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
#0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:33:7)
#1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:659:37)
#2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:853:21)
<asynchronous suspension>
#
3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:574:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      _Flutt
erFrontendCompiler.compile (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:43:22)
#5      starter (package:flu
tter_frontend_server/server.dart:182:27)
#6      main (file:///C:/b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/fl
utter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:9:30)
#7      _startIsolate.<ano
nymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:299:32)
#8      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_pa
tch.dart:168:12)



FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\Users\my name\Desktop\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 896

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Users\my name\Desktop\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 13s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1'
```

---

and this is my pubSpec.yaml file

```
name: flutter_app
description: A new Flutter application.

# The following line prevents the package from being accidentally published to
# pub.dev using `pub publish`. This is preferred for private packages.
publish_to: 'none' # Remove this line if you wish to publish to pub.dev

# The following defines the version and build number for your application.
# A version number is three numbers separated by dots, like 1.2.43
# followed by an optional build number separated by a +.
# Both the version and the builder number may be overridden in flutter
# build by specifying --build-name and --build-number, respectively.
# In Android, build-name is used as versionName while build-number used as versionCode.
# Read more about Android versioning at https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning
# In iOS, build-name is used as CFBundleShortVersionString while build-number used as CFBundleVersion.
# Read more about iOS versioning at
# https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter


  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  
  firebase_auth: ^0.16.1



dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

# For information on the generic Dart part of this file, see the
# following page: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/pubspec

# The following section is specific to Flutter.
flutter:

  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

fonts:
  - family: PhoneIcon
    fonts:
      - asset: Icons/PhoneIcon.ttf
  # To add assets to your application, add an assets section, like this:
  # assets:
  #   - images/a_dot_burr.jpeg
  #   - images/a_dot_ham.jpeg

  # An image asset can refer to one or more resolution-specific "variants", see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#resolution-aware.

  # For details regarding adding assets from package dependencies, see
  # https://flutter.dev/assets-and-images/#from-packages

  # To add custom fonts to your application, add a fonts section here,
  # in this "flutter" section. Each entry in this list should have a
  # "family" key with the font family name, and a "fonts" key with a
  # list giving the asset and other descriptors for the font. For
  # example:






  # For details regarding fonts from package dependencies,
  # see https://flutter.dev/custom-fonts/#from-packages
```

Comment: try to delete the pubspec.lock file, run `flutter packages get` and then to run your application again

Comment: I tried this method but didn't help and thank you for your help